# mysql where from an array json

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

ive ben sick with this problem, i have an array but in json format, i get that from select2 multiple values ex (name=place[]),
but its like this :

```
Array ( [0] => Hematology Rutin [1] => Eritrosit )
```

with print_r.

and heres the question .
how can i select * from product where name IN ('".$array."')
.

how can i expode that array to and simple php array like this

```
$array = "Hematology,Eritrosit"
```

il try to `echo json_encode($lab);` but its turn like this `["Hematology Rutin","Eritrosit"]`
i hope someone can help me.. thanks

Comment: The notation is `IN (?,?)` where`?` is a placeholder you bind data to. You can't just arbitrarily encode it in JSON and expect it to work. The documentation lays it out in extremely precise terms if you care to look, which I encourage you to do.

Answer (score 0):

Covert json to array. Then convert array to string as you want and use in query.

Something like below:

```
$array = json_decode($json, TRUE);   // convert json to array
$list = implode ('\',\'', $array);  // Convert array to string
```

Use in SQL query

```
$sql = "select * from product where name IN ('" . $list . "')";
```